# jQuery Plugin | Why doesn't this part of it work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code, it's a bit to long, and ignore the `opts`, it should work without that too, but it seems like there is something I am doing wrong because nothing happens.

```
 var container = 'body';

 var structureWrapper = '<div class="content-login"></div>';

 var structure = [
'<form name="', opts.formClass, '" class="', opts.formClass, '" method="post" action="#">',
    '<fieldset class="', opts.fieldsWrapper, '">',
        '<fieldset class="', opts.userWrapper, '">',
            '<label for="', opts.userInt, '" class="', opts.userLbl, '"><img src="', opts.userIcon, '" alt="', opts.userName, '" /></label>',
            '<input type="text" name="', opts.userInt, '" class="', opts.userInt, '" placeholder="', checkNameLenght(opts.userName, namesLenght.userNameLenght, 16, 'Username'), '" value="" autocomplete="off" />',
        '</fieldset>',
        '<fieldset class="', opts.passWrapper, '">',
            '<label for="', opts.passInt, '" class="', opts.passLbl, '"><img src="', opts.passIcon, '" alt="', opts.passName, '" /></label>',
            '<input type="password" name="', opts.passInt, '" class="', opts.passInt, '" placeholder="', checkNameLenght(opts.passName, namesLenght.passNameLenght, 16, 'Password'), '" value="" autocomplete="off" />',
        '</fieldset>',
        '<fieldset class="', opts.btnWrapper, '">',
            '<button type="submit" name="', opts.btnInt, '" class="', opts.btnInt, '">', checkNameLenght(opts.btnName, namesLenght.btnNameLenght, 7, 'Login'), '</button>',
        '</fieldset>',
    '</fieldset>',
    '<div class="toogle-button">',
        '<ul class="inside">',
            '<li class="toogle"><a><img src="assets/gfx/toogle.png" alt="Back" /></a></li>',
        '</ul>',
    '</div>',
'</form>',
'<div class="toogle-buttons">',
'</div>'
];





var getProps = function(obj) {
return {
    'position': 'absolute',
    'top': (($(window).height() - $(obj).outerHeight()) / 2) + 'px',
    'left': (($(window).width() - $(obj).outerWidth()) / 2) + 'px'
}
}

var showObj = function(obj, callback) {
return setTimeout(function() {
    if (opts.centerObj === true) {
        var cssProps = getProps(obj);
        obj.css(cssProps).fadeIn('slow');
    }
    else {
        obj.fadeIn('slow');
    }
    if (typeof callback == 'function') {
        callback.call(this);
    }
}, 1500);
}


var appendStructure = function(wrapper, structure, cls) {

return $(wrapper).appendTo(container).hide(function() {
    var obj = $(container).find(cls);
    $(structure.join('')).appendTo(obj);
    showObj(obj, function() {
        if (opts.centerObj === true) {
            $(window).resize(function() {
                var cssProps = getProps(obj);
                obj.css(cssProps);
            });
        }
    });
});
}

appendStructure(structureWrapper, structure, '.content-login');
```

What it's suppose to do is take that array and concatenate it and then append it to the container, `body` in my case, and then fade the content in. Can you spot anything I'm doing wrong ?

I appreciate the help :) You also have a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/VUjMH/ .

Comment: Aside from your issue, let me kindly let you know that you have misspelled "length" as "lenght".

Comment: I know that, I was mentioned before, but it doesn't affect the code, it's a `var` I have defined.

Comment: How can we ignore `opts`? You're using it without defining it for us, so how can we try to debug this?

Comment: If you delete them you get the same result, they aren't relevant for what this part of the code should do, they are relevant further in my plugin. As you can see they are either for debugging in the console, classes inside the form and the labels or placeholders in the form, I assume it's not important for you to see that too, it's the main functionality that doesn't work, what is suppose to do. That is why I asked, because even if I have all those defined vars and functions still it doesn't work. It should work as standalone code too

Comment: If opts error is removed, it works. Check it http://jsfiddle.net/VUjMH/2/. Is it not how it is supposed to work?

Comment: Works when you remove everything `opts`-related. see http://jsfiddle.net/6ebTd/

Comment: Yes, let's remove the opts and leave the form as it is, why isn't that way working as it should here http://jsfiddle.net/6ebTd/ ? I mean a form should be build and appended to the container so that it could be faded in ..

Comment: @Roland, what doesn't work? http://jsfiddle.net/VUjMH/3/

Comment: Well, look at my fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/VUjMH/4/ , on my side nothing works ...

Comment: Same thing. opts is causing the error. Add var opts = {} and then it would work. You cannot assume that opts is not needed when all your code accesses it. Check it http://jsfiddle.net/VUjMH/5/

Comment: OK. But in my plugin I have all the opts and the functions as in the fiddle, and the opts are all there and defined but still no result, and if I use this piece of code : http://jsfiddle.net/Kpjc2/ , on my end in the plugin everything works just fine, so the problem would be with the `appendStructure ()` function I guess, but what is the problem with it ?

Comment: In the above fiddle there is no includes? You have to show whole code for us to be able to help.

Comment: The whole code has about 800 lines of code for now, so I don't think that would be smart :) I showed you in that fiddle with what I'm replacing `appendStructure()` function from within the posted question and it works, but when I want to use that function `appendStructure ()` nothing happens. So replacing `appendStructure ()` with the fiddle above : jsfiddle.net/Kpjc2 ; makes the rest of the code work, so, why is that happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code fails over when there are no opts properties set since you can't carry out concatenation on something that has no means of first being translated into a string.

Throughout your code the word  "length" was misspelled "lenght"

Apart from that I've been through the code form jsfiddle and brought it up to a point where it works.

I've made a small change to the  "checkNameLength" function, removing the "namesLength" parameter and replacing instances of it with "name.length"

```
var container = 'body';
 var opts = {
    debug: true,
     formClass:"",
     userWrapper:"",
     userInt:"",
     userLbl:"",
     userIcon:"" ,
     userName:"",
     passName:"",
     btnName:""
 }

  /*Removed redundant namesLength var*/   
 var checkNameLength = function(name, allowedLength, defaultName) {
     if ((name.length<= allowedLength) && !(/\s[^a-z]/i.test(name))) {
         return name;
     }
     else {
         if (opts.debug === true) {
             console.log(name + ' is to long or contains special characters / numbers | Please      choose a name shorter than ' + allowedLength+ ' characters or remove any character / number');
         }
         return defaultName;
     }
 }


 var structureWrapper = '<div class="content-login"></div>';

 var structure = [
     '<form name="', opts.formClass, '" class="', opts.formClass, '" method="post" action="#">',
    '<fieldset class="', opts.fieldsWrapper, '">',
        '<fieldset class="', opts.userWrapper, '">',
            '<label for="', opts.userInt, '" class="', opts.userLbl, '"><img src="', opts.userIcon, '" alt="', opts.userName, '" /></label>',
            '<input type="text" name="', opts.userInt, '" class="', opts.
userInt, '" placeholder="', checkNameLength(opts.userName,  16, 'Username'), '" value="" autocomplete="off" />',
        '</fieldset>',
        '<fieldset class="', opts.passWrapper, '">',
            '<label for="', opts.passInt, '" class="', opts.passLbl, '"><img src="', opts.passIcon, '" alt="', opts.passName, '" /></label>',
            '<input type="password" name="', opts.passInt, '" class="', opts.passInt, '" placeholder="', checkNameLength(opts.passName, 16, 'Password'), '" value="" autocomplete="off" />',
        '</fieldset>',
        '<fieldset class="', opts.btnWrapper, '">',
            '<button type="submit" name="', opts.btnInt, '" class="', opts.btnInt, '">', checkNameLength(opts.btnName, 7, 'Login'), '</button>',
        '</fieldset>',
    '</fieldset>',
    '<div class="toogle-button">',
        '<ul class="inside">',
            '<li class="toogle"><a><img src="assets/gfx/toogle.png" alt="Back" /></a></li>',
        '</ul>',
    '</div>',
'</form>',
'<div class="toogle-buttons">',
'</div>'
];





var getProps = function(obj) {
    return {
        'position': 'absolute',
        'top': (($(window).height() - $(obj).outerHeight()) / 2) + 'px',
        'left': (($(window).width() - $(obj).outerWidth()) / 2) + 'px'
     }
 }

 var showObj = function(obj, callback) {
     return setTimeout(function() {
         if (opts.centerObj === true) {
             var cssProps = getProps(obj);
             obj.css(cssProps).fadeIn('slow');
         }
         else {
             obj.fadeIn('slow');
        }
         if (typeof callback == 'function') {
            callback.call(this);
         }
     }, 1500);
 }


 var appendStructure = function(wrapper, structure, cls) {

     return $(wrapper).appendTo(container).hide(function() {
         var obj = $(container).find(cls);
         $(structure.join('')).appendTo(obj);
         showObj(obj, function() {
             if (opts.centerObj === true) {
                 $(window).resize(function() {
                     var cssProps = getProps(obj);
                     obj.css(cssProps);
                 });
             }
         });
     });
 }

 appendStructure(structureWrapper, structure, '.content-login');
```

Comment: thank you. But that's not the problem that I've encountered. I know that lenght is misspelled, but I did it on purpose, I'll later modify it perhaps. As for the `namesLength` parameter, it's like that for a reason, I have a lot of names and I've placed all the names lengths in that object, that is why it looks like that. I was looking for some syntax errors that I've might missed, because no matter how I try, inside my plugin it doesn't work, but I think I have found a lead. Thanks again :)

Comment: No worries.

If you don't mind me saying, I'm concerned with your comment "As for the 'namesLength'...". For one thing storing the length in a independent variable breaks association with the string and secondly, I can't imagine where it would be practical to disassociate the length from the string, it appears to be a dangerous game to play.

Comment: you're right, maybe I'll find another way to have the length.

Comment: That's sort of my point, you already have the length so there's no reason to store it anywhere else. If you need it within a function call for whatever reason you could use (example) higherThanSix(stringVar.length) - where the function returns val > 6